# In Bootstrap how do I align Heading text with Alert text

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

In Bootstrap how do I align Heading text with Alert text

So I am using **alert** class on this page, then a heading and then another alert. Because the alerts are within a box the txt starts further right that the text in the heading. Now I know I can align the text in the heading further to the right using **mx-2** class but having to add these extra margins everywhere indicates to me I am doing something in a non Bootstrap way.

Should the heading be within something else so that it automatically lines up with alerts.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<main class='container-fluid'>
  <h1 class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    Preview Only, no actual changes will be made to your music files
  </h1>
  <h1 >
    Fix Songs Report 396
  </h1>
  <div>
    <h3>
      Errors and Warnings
    </h3>
    <div>

      <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
        <h5 class="alert-heading">
          Mar 23, 2019, 2:42:06 PM
        </h5>

        <p>
          Warning:Naim E:\Melco\TestMusic\TestMusic\TestMusic\WAV\Music\Various Artists\Pure Rock Ballads:AmgInfo.xml Track Count doesnt match No Of Songs so ignoring track metadata:Song Count 36:Track Count 19
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

[image: screenshot showing problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the text that you need to align in a "card" element:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<main class='container-fluid'>
  <h1 class="alert alert-danger custom-alert" role="alert">
    Preview Only, no actual changes will be made to your music files
  </h1>

  <div class="card" style="border:0">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h1>
        Fix Songs Report 396
      </h1>

      <h3>
        Errors and Warnings
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="alert alert-warning custom-alert" role="alert">
      <h5 class="alert-heading">
        Mar 23, 2019, 2:42:06 PM
      </h5>

      <p>
        Warning:Naim E:\Melco\TestMusic\TestMusic\TestMusic\WAV\Music\Various Artists\Pure Rock Ballads:AmgInfo.xml Track Count doesnt match No Of Songs so ignoring track metadata:Song Count 36:Track Count 19
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</main>
```

PS: Why do you use so many empty div tags?

PSS: please remove this: **style="border:0** if you want to keep the border for the card

Comment: Card, hmm that may be the way to go I will investigate. The html is generated by j2html java library and that has caused me to use a few more divs sometimes because i neeed to return a single tag from a methos, i,e rather than return a h1 and h3 tag i wrap in a div and return a div.

Comment: @PaulTaylor, I suggested card because it will always have the same padding as the alert.

Comment: im not totally  sure about this, but seems to work better so marking as correct, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no bootstrap way to achive your goal. The alert boxes intend to have a different margin than the headings.

I would recommend to change the order of the elements. First the heading, then the errors and then the warnings and leave the margins as there are.

The other way is, as you said before, add a custom css class with margin-left to all elements. 
Perhaps you can work with global classes for h1-h5.

**Edit:**

So I think it's a matter of taste. Here is another way, wrap your content in a colorless alert box, so you get the same margin.

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>

    <body>

      <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          <h1>
            Preview Only, no actual changes will be made to your music files
          </h1>
        </div>

        <div class="alert">
          <h1>Fix Songs Report 396</h1>
          <h3>Errors and Warnings</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
          <h5 class="alert-heading">
            Mar 23, 2019, 2:42:06 PM
          </h5>

          <p>
            Warning:Naim E:\Melco\TestMusic\TestMusic\TestMusic\WAV\Music\Various Artists\Pure Rock Ballads:AmgInfo.xml
            Track Count doesnt match No Of Songs so ignoring track metadata:Song Count 36:Track Count 19
          </p>
        </div>

      </div>

      <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
      <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: I can see putting the first alert beneath the first header may look better but I was thinking that maybe the headings should be within some other element so then lined up with the alerts ?

Comment: Colourless alert is a nice idea, but I cant help but feeling that its not a matter of taste, it just looks really bad for the text to not be aligned, which is why I think I am creating my pages incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

This issue only resolved by overriding the **bootstrap alert CSS** and this is not good practice. I just add **overriding CSS** in the below code snippet I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
.custom-alert {
  padding: 10px !important;
  margin: 0 -10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<main class='container-fluid'>
  <h1 class="alert alert-danger custom-alert" role="alert">
    Preview Only, no actual changes will be made to your music files
  </h1>
  <h1 >
    Fix Songs Report 396
  </h1>
  <div>
    <h3>
      Errors and Warnings
    </h3>
    <div>

      <div class="alert alert-warning custom-alert" role="alert">
        <h5 class="alert-heading">
          Mar 23, 2019, 2:42:06 PM
        </h5>

        <p>
          Warning:Naim E:\Melco\TestMusic\TestMusic\TestMusic\WAV\Music\Various Artists\Pure Rock Ballads:AmgInfo.xml Track Count doesnt match No Of Songs so ignoring track metadata:Song Count 36:Track Count 19
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Well yes I dont want to do bad practise, I want to find out how I should be constructing my pages so this is not an issue

Answer (score -1):

you can try using the

```
<div class="container">    
<h1 class="text-center display-4">
```

the first, tag it helps center all your contents .so place the tag at the start of the body.
second tag is my personal favorite header class. Its very simple and i have used it in many of my projects. 
hope this helps :)

Comment: I dont want to center the contet, but what does display-4 do ?